# How to pause debugguer while entity framework has a "Save" transaction in progress?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, debugging, transactions

I would like to pause the debugguer while entity framework has a "Save" transaction in progress. This way, I could easily look at what is currently locked in the database because of the uncommitted transaction. I want to do this, because I'm suspecting that something is locked and it shouldn't be.

Back in days with SQLDataAdapter, I could bind an event on "onRowUpdated" and set my breakpoint there.

I have found a "SavingChanges" event, but it doesn't seem to be raised within the transaction.

```
public class MyDB: DbContext
{
    public MyDB()
        : base("MyConnectionString")
    {
        var oc = this as IObjectContextAdapter;
        oc.ObjectContext.SavingChanges -= ObjectContext_SavingChanges;
        oc.ObjectContext.SavingChanges += ObjectContext_SavingChanges;           
    }

    private void ObjectContext_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Please note that I do not specify a transaction manually. I just modify a bunch of entity in the "MyDB" before calling "MyDB.SaveChanges()" and I assume method SaveChanges is responsible for starting a transaction for saving all changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way.
Setting manually the transaction allow me to add a breakpoint before it's committed.

```
        using (var t = ((DbContext)MyDb).Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                MyDb.SaveChanges();
                t.Commit();//Break point here
            }
            catch
            {
                t.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

This way I was able to sneak in the database to see what is locked and I indeed found that something was locked without reason.